# How to write an python API for email send for success and failed?

Tags: python

I have just started coding in python (beginner). I have written a code to send an email but sometimes its getting failed to send and throwing an error when i provide own server details "smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected" and on other hand if i provide gmail SMTP details it is working fine.

Things I want to do:

1. How to write an if else condition for this code. (if connection: SUCCESS (mail sent) or if FAILED then exact error statement)
2. About the server details, how should I configure the server details in it?
3. How to give username and password in a variable instead giving directly in **s.login('USERNAME','PASSWORD')** . Example: USERNAME: abc@xyz.com, PASSWORD: pass
4. If there is no email provided, it should throw an error.

My code:

```
def email():
    email = request.form.get('email')
   
    s = smtplib.SMTP(host='abc123456.server.net', port=25)
    s.starttls()
    s.login('hello@email.com', 'password')

    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content('Thanks for registering with us!')

    msg['Subject'] = 'Welcome to 2021!'
    msg['From'] = 'John <john@doe.com>'
    msg['To'] = f'{email}'

    s.send_message(msg)
    s.quit()
    return 'Email sent!'
```

Can you please help me out with the above said issues.

I know I'm asking a lot but can't help it, i'm still learning.
Thanks in advance. Hope someone help!

Comment: I'd recommend to first get your basics clear on python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code to solve few problems you highlighted above.

```
import smtplib, ssl

def email():
    email = request.form.get('email')

    # Set your connection variables
    host = "abc123456.server.net"
    port = 587 # For secure connection

    # Request user input
    sender_email = input('Enter your email address: ')
    password = input("Type your password and press enter: ") 

    # Create a secure SSL context
    context = ssl.create_default_context()

    try:   
        s = smtplib.SMTP(host, port)
        s.starttls(context=context) # Kindly note you can only starttls in port 587
        s.login(sender_email, password)

        msg = EmailMessage()
        msg.set_content('Thanks for registering with us!')

        msg['Subject'] = 'Welcome to 2021!'
        msg['From'] = 'John <john@doe.com>'
        msg['To'] = f'{email}'

        s.send_message(msg)
        s.quit()
        return 'Email sent!'

    except Exception as e:
        # Print errors out
        print(e)
```

What i can recommend you to do before setting up the connection port, is to verify which port for smtp is open in your mail server. You can henceforth test connection to that port using telnet tool in command prompt:

```
telnet yourserverdomain port
```

Example:

```
telnet abc123456.server.net 25
```

You can test as many ports as you can.
If it fails then you will need to open it. Check as well if your mail server can resolve DNS.

On last question, verify if that the email you are referring to is the form email or your email.

Comment: Refer this article https://www.mailgun.com/blog/which-smtp-port-understanding-ports-25-465-587/

Answer (score 0):

For your 1st question, I would say use the try and exception block.
2. Make it a more clear question.
3. I suppose you want the user to fill in the username and password so make an input line

```
x=input("Enter your email:")
```

usually, it is in string format so if you want an integer just do-

```
x=int(input("Enter your number:"))
```

4. follow the first step to keep an exception